# sending rpc_client message from a react project

Tags: python, reactjs, rabbitmq, rpc, send

how can i send a RPC message (based on rabbitmq)from a reactJs project in frontend to a python project in backend .
i tried to use amqplib to send my message but i think i can't use it in a browser .
any help !
this is my code :

```
export function callService() {
    var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
    amqp.connect('amqp://localhost:8000', function (err, conn) {



        console.log("gggggggg")

        conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
            var q = 'frontend';
            var msg = 'Hello!';

            let messsage_body="http://www.documents.sergic.com/photos/photo-location-appartement-1-piece-pontoise-95300_563687_1_101_S.JPG";
            var headers={'type': 'get_similarity', 'customer': 'sergic'};
            console.log('cc ', num);

            ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg) {
                if (msg.properties.correlationId === corr) {
                    console.log(' [.] Got %s', msg.content.toString());
                    setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);
                }
           }, {noAck: true});
    });
}
```

and i want to run it in a browser by clicking on a picture !